# Calculation of average of sums is very slow

Tags: plotting, summation

I have these functions

```
f[x_, n_] := 4/\[Pi] Sum[Sin[(2 k + 1) x]/(2 k + 1), {k, 0, n - 1}];
\[Sigma][x_, m_] := 1/m Sum[f[x, k], {k, 1, m}];
```

If I do:

```
Plot[{\[Sigma][x, 500]}, {x, -0.01, 0.01}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1.2, 1.2}}]
```

It is painfully slow. Is there any way to speed this up without too much work (it is just for illustration purposes)? Since this is just average of sums, I would have guessed that there might be an easy way Mathematica can simplify this but, e.g. when i tried to plot `\[Sigma][x, 5000]`, i had to abort after several hours.

Comment: What is $q$ in the second line of code (inside the Plot[])?

Comment: @HansOlo Sorry, I forgot to adapt the code, it is just a constant, there is no need to plot the Signum function and that q, I adjusted the question code accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, n_] = 
 Assuming[{Element[n, Integers], n >= 1}, 
  4/π Sum[Sin[(2 k + 1) x]/(2 k + 1), {k, 0, n - 1}] // 
   FullSimplify]

(* (1/π)I (2 ArcCoth[E^(I x)] - 2 ArcTanh[E^(I x)] - 
   E^(-I (x + 2 n x)) LerchPhi[E^(-2 I x), 1, 1/2 + n] + 
   E^(I (x + 2 n x)) LerchPhi[E^(2 I x), 1, 1/2 + n]) *)

σ[x_, m_Integer?Positive] := 1/m Sum[f[x, k], {k, 1, m}]

Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[σ[x, m], {m, 500, 100, -100}],
 {x, -0.01, 0.01},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1.2, 1.2}},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[Range[500, 100, -100],
    LegendLabel -> m], {.25, .75}],
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: Much better but still gets quite slow for large `m`.